# change content of div twice in one go

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am doing a simple ajax call, and it is working fine. However, the response is slow, and I do not want the user to click twice thinking it is not working. Therefore, I would like to show a message such as "Converting please wait" before receiving the response. Here is the code that I have tried:

```
function postajax()
{
    document.getElementById('linksarea').innerHTML = "<img src='images/waiting.gif'> Converting please wait...";

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            document.getElementById("links").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

    var links = window.document.getElementById('linksarea').value;

    xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("links="+links+"&username=xxxx");
}
```

here is the html section thay i'm trying to modify

```
<div id="memberright">
  Convert the links here<br />
  <textarea name="links" id="linksarea" cols="65" rows="10"></textarea><br />
  <input type="button" id="buttonr" onclick="postajax()" value="Convert">
</div>

<div id="ajax">
  <div id="links">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the corresponding html? Also what does "its not doing what i want" mean? What is it actually doing?

Comment: any reason why you're not using a javascript library like jQuery? Would save you some compatibility headaches.

Comment: Is this not working ?? document.getElementById('linksarea').innerHTML = "<img src='images/waiting.gif'> Converting please wait...";

Comment: @Nebojsac I agree that using a library such as jQuery is definitely easier, however jquery has some compatability issues with versions prior to IE6. Why would you want to support browsers prior to IE 7 in general, I do not know, but it may be a requirement for the OP.

Comment: What is linksarea? I have seen lines window.document.getElementById('linksarea').value;   and  document.getElementById('linksarea').innerHTML = "<img src='images/waiting.gif'> Converting please wait...";    These innerHTML and value for same control looks strange.

Comment: @JoshMein good luck to the OP then :) 
But I do agree that he's asking for a javascript solution. I just can't shake the feeling that he'll be back often if he continues using vanilla javascript.

Comment: Hello guys, the code is 100% it was just a typo. but what is the equivalent jquery code for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using:

```
document.getElementById('linksarea').innerHTML = "<img src='images/waiting.gif'>
   Converting please wait...";
```

which should set the `innerHTML` to the loading image and display a loading message.  At a later point you are taking the value of that element:

```
window.document.getElementById('linksarea').value;
```

The `value` attribute will only exist on an input, which would not have `innerHTML`.

Try the following, assuming `#links` is the element you're wanting to modify, which according to your question's title you are trying to change the value of a `div` element twice:

```
document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = "<img src='images/waiting.gif'>
       Converting please wait..."; 

// or if you have another div with an ID of `linksarea`

document.getElementById("linksarea").innerHTML = "<img src='images/waiting.gif'>
       Converting please wait...";
```

I could be completely wrong without seeing your HTML but that looks as though that could be your problem.  You need to make sure you are trying to modify the correct element.

**Update:**

Using jQuery:

```
function postajax(){
    $('#links').html("<img src='images/waiting.gif'> Converting please wait...");

    var params = "links=" + $('#linksarea').val() + "&username=xxxx";

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: params,
        success: function(result){
            $('#links').html(result)
        }
    }); 
}
```

As demonstrated, jQuery greatly simplifies executing AJAX requests with the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function.  I would suggest that you understand what is happening behind the scenes before utilizing a library so that you are able to fully understand verything.  This will help encourage much more positive behavior and tendencies.

Comment: thank you this is the answer, it was a typo i wasn't updating the right elements

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to acheive the desired result using jQuery, instead of pure JavaScript per your inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

try adding another if statement to the onreadystatechange function.  The state value for "loading" (which is what I think you're looking for) is '1'.  Use this for reference: [peach pit](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=443580&seqNum=2).  Basically, you're looking to make it look like this:

```
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
          document.getElementById("links").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
      else if (xmlhttp.readyState==1 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById('linksarea').innerHTML = "<img src='images/waiting.gif'> Converting please wait...";
      }
  }
```